# Prove that every finite subset of $\Bbb R^d$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Euclidean Space -Analysis Proof Question:**

Prove that every finite subset of $\Bbb R^d$ is closed

*Please show all details of a proof so I can understand the reasoning.  I am not sure how to formally show this one, but I do believe it would be by somehow showing its complement is open.*

Comment: Your suspicion is correct. How might you show something is open?

Comment: What've you tried?Hint:First show that set containing only one element is closed?

Comment: What is your definition of a closed set?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a detailed (but you have to fill the proof) answer (by the way your guess is good, it is about the complement).

Take $X=\{x_1,...,x_N\}$ to be a finite subset.

Take $y\notin X$ and show that you can find a ball $B(y,r)$ around $y$ of finite radius $r>0$ such that $B(y,r)\cap X=\emptyset$ (draw some pictures ! Here they might help you).

If you cannot do it, try with $N=1$ (it should be easier) then $N=2$ (after this, it should be clear).

Use your definitions of closed sets and open sets to conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways of proving this:

$1.$
Let $A=\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$. We can express $A$ as $\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{x_i\}$. Each singleton is closed so the union of finitely many closed sets is still closed

$2.$ If you can use continuous functions, here is an argument:

- If $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ is continuous then its zero set is closed. 
  The zero set of $f$ is $\{ x \in \mathbb R^d : f(x)=0 \}$.
- Every finite set $\{ a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n} \}$ is the zero set of the continuous function $f(x)=(x-a_{1})(x-a_{2})\cdots(x-a_{n})$ and so is closed

Comment: I like the first approach! Much more elegant than my solution.

Comment: @goblin Thank you,Regards.